# Find certain child element with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

When an element with the class `.parent` is hovered over, it locates child elements with the class `.child` and applies the CSS to them.

[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92HzD/)

Is it possible to achieve this effect purely with CSS?

**html:**

```
<div class="parent" style="background:red;margin:20px;padding:20px;">
    <div class="child" style="background:blue;margin:20px;padding:20px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent" style="background:red;margin:20px;padding:20px;">
    <div class="child" style="background:blue;margin:20px;padding:20px;"></div>
</div>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.parent').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.child').css('background','yellow');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('.child').css('background','blue');
  }
);​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the inline styles and put the following in a stylesheet:

```
/* CSS */
.parent { background: red; margin: 20px; padding: 20px; }
.child {background blue; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;}
.parent:hover > .child { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: No problem : ) really useful little trick. see this article for more useful selectors: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: OK. Assuming he takes out the inline styles and moves them to the style sheet.

Comment: Yes, or `!important` to override inline styling.

Comment: @UserIsCorrupt: You should avoid using the `!important` declaration whenever possible.

Comment: You may also have some browser compatibility issues, if the ">" isn't necessary, I would remove it (ie. if there are no other children with the class "child" it is unnecessary, and fixed one possible issue if you are worried about old browsers…

Comment: @animuson: Can you elaborate on that? Because our CSS guys use !important on  few styles, specially for styles relating to client side validation messages so no one can mess with them and break the intended unified look. Seems to make sense.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl [!important CSS Declarations: How and When to Use Them](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) - "!important declarations **should not be used unless they are absolutely necessary** after all other avenues have been exhausted"

Comment: @animuson: I looked at the article and it says a lot about not using !important and it says a lot about people using it not knowing CSS and only keeping !important for special cases. It goes on about the cons being that you interrupt the natural flow of your rules. That is all good advise but is there an actual functional negative reason why !important is bad? I'm only asking cause if I don't want anyone to over-write something is that not then my natural flow of my rules? I will try not to use it myself as I assume it is bad going by the article.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: No. It's more of an indicator. If you have to use it, your CSS probably isn't written well and anyone else who has to work with it is going to have a hell of a time figuring out which rules are being applied and overwritten.

Comment: @animuson: I see. I was looking for some functional negative impact when using it. What you saying makes sense and following good advise and getting into good habits is always good. Thanks for your response on that.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: the main negative of using `!important` is that it makes your code less easy to change later on. When two style rules apply to the same element, the one with the more specific selector wins, unless you use `!important`, in which case that one will *always* win. That’s fine until you *want* to override it, in which case you have to use `!important` in a later rule, which is fine until you want to override *that* one, and so on until you’ve got `!important`’s scattered throughout your stylesheet, when you really should have fixed the specificity problem you originally had.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

```
.parent .child {
    background: blue;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

That replicates the effect your jQuery has. If you literally mean “child” (as opposed to descendant, which is what you’re actually finding), then you want the following:

```
.parent > .child {
    background: blue;
}

.parent:hover > .child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

As [@hobbs notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117871/20578), this doesn’t work in IE 6, because [`:hover` is only supported on links in IE 6](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Ahover).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you should move your inline styles into the classes as well so you don't have to use the `!important` declaration (otherwise the inline styles will always override the style sheet).

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>​
```

```css
.parent {
    background: red;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.child {
    background: blue;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w5WgQ/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent .child {
    background: blue;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Should do the job, except on versions of IE where `:hover` only works on `A` elements (jQuery works around this; CSS doesn't.)